# How can I conditionally point an iOS app to a QA or PROD environment depending on where it's downloaded from?

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

Essentially I would like a single build of my app to point to 2 different environments QA and PROD depending on where it's downloaded from, would this be a good future proof way to accomplish it? Based on this conditional I would point the app to either/or baseurl.

The background for why I need to do this is my team tests in QA from TestFlight and wants to deploy to the app store once all good. I also want to avoid pushing 2 builds to app store, 1 pointing to QA and 1 to PROD when QA is complete.

I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    var isProduction: Bool {
        #if DEBUG
            return false
        #else
            guard let path = self.appStoreReceiptURL?.path else {
                return true
            }
            return !path.contains("sandboxReceipt")
        #endif
    }
}

if Bundle.main.isProduction {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Not that I know of. Besides, it's not just the endpoints, but I also like to use different bundle identifiers (so QA and production builds can coexist on the same device at the same time), different icons (so testers are never confused as to which environment they're going against), etc. All of this lends itself to having two separate builds.

Answer (score 0):

When an application is installed through TestFlight Beta, the receipt file has a different name compared to the usual installation. Instead of being named `"receipt"` it is named `"sandboxReceipt"` and is located in the `"StoreKit"` directory.

In Swift, you can determine if the application is running through TestFlight Beta by checking the last path component of the `appStoreReceiptURL` obtained from the main bundle.

Here is the Swift code:

```
if let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL {
    let isDownloadedFromTestFlight = receiptURL.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt"
    // Use the value of isDownloadedFromTestFlight to determine if the app is running through TestFlight Beta
}
```

Comment: Have you personally tried this approach before? I've seen some mixed opinions on this